# Unable to import Expo from 'expo'. in react native

Tags: react-native

I tried to import Expo from 'expo'. But I am getting an error as:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `expo` from `C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\App.js`: Module `expo` does not exist in the Haste module map.

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:273:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
    at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:391:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:388:18)
    at C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:261:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\reactnative\navigate\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

**Dependencies in package.json**

{
  "name": "navigate",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: What are your dependencies in `package.json`?